# How to remove row after being deleted from its endpoint

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can I update the table when some event is deleted? The action is deleting the event from DB, however, the row is there. How can I remove the row after using the function DeleteThis.

```
  <div id="profile-dashboard-content-events">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Title</td>
                    <td>Delete</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var theEvent in Model.EventsList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@theEvent.Id</td>
                        <td>@theEvent.ShortTitle</td>
                        <td>
                            <a onclick="DeleteThis(@theEvent.Id)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt iicon cursor-pointer"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    
    
                }
    
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <small style="color:#e0e0e0;">*Clear the last @_config["NumberOfEvents"], will delete the oldest @_config["NumberOfEvents"] events </small>
        <br />
        <small style="color:#e0e0e0;">*Delete past events, will delete all expired events </small>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        function DeleteThis(theEventId) {
            var baseUrl = "https://localhost:44380/Event/Delete";
            var requestUrl = baseUrl + "?eventId=" + theEventId;
            var data = {
                eventId: theEventId
            };
            axios.delete(requestUrl, data)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
    
            })
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using pure JavaScript. In your `onclick` pass in `this`, which is a reference to the element that has been clicked. E.g: `<a onclick="DeleteThis(@theEvent.Id, this)">`

In your `DeleteThis` method add a parameter, and then call `parentElement` to traverse up the DOM tree to find the table row. Then remove the table row using `remove()`. E.g:

```
function DeleteThis(theEventId, ctrl) {             
  ctrl.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
}
```

Heres a basic example (without any asp.net) https://jsfiddle.net/6yLja3v0/